# Replace null values based on other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns (but posting only col1, col2, col3 here for simplified post):

```
id    col1       col2    col3   source_id
a1    765.3      234     cat    a5
a2    3298.3     none    dog    a4
a3    8762.1     27      rat    a8
a4    none       none    none   none       
a5    none       none    none   a6
a6    none       none    none   none
```

I want to fill `none values of source _id` with `values from id`.
For example, `source_id a5 row has none` which has to replaced with `id a1 values`, subsequently, `source_id a6 row having none` to be replaced with `a5 row`

Output:

```
id    col1       col2    col3   source_id
a1    765.3      234     cat    a5
a2    3298.3     none    dog    a4
a3    8762.1     27      rat    a8
a4    3298.3     none    dog    none       
a5    765.3      234     cat    a6
a6    765.3      234     cat    none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First seems `none` are strings, so replace them to missing values:

```
df = df.mask(df.eq('none'), None)
```

Then create dictionary in `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html):

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(df[['id','source_id']].dropna().itertuples(index=False))

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)
# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1

print (node2id)
{'a6': 1, 'a5': 1, 'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'a4': 2, 'a8': 3, 'a3': 3}
```

Last groups by mapped `id` column and replace `None`s by forward and back filling:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['id'].map(node2id))
         .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
         .assign(source_id = df['source_id']))
print (df1)
   id    col1  col2 col3 source_id
0  a1   765.3   234  cat        a5
1  a2  3298.3  None  dog        a4
2  a3  8762.1    27  rat        a8
3  a4  3298.3  None  dog      None
4  a5   765.3   234  cat        a6
5  a6   765.3   234  cat      None
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should do is set the id column as the index, so you look up the row to populate your cells

```
df = df.set_index('id')
```

Then you can just loop over the columns and fill them

```py
for col in df.columns:
if col == 'source_id':
    continue
for idx in df.index:
    dst_idx = df.source_id[idx]
    if (df[col][idx] != 'none'
            and dst_idx != 'none'
            and dst_idx in df.index and
            df[col][dst_idx] == 'none'):
        df[col][dst_idx] = df[col][idx]
```

```py
      col1  col2 col3 source_id
id
a1   765.3   234  cat        a5
a2  3298.3  none  dog        a4
a3  8762.1    27  rat        a8
a4  3298.3  none  dog      none
a5   765.3   234  cat        a6
a6   765.3   234  cat      none
```